# JSON.parse with json_encode and html

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, escaping

I have got the following html string:
`$htmlString = '<div class="foo">bar</div>';`

I would like to json_encode this string and parse this in a javascript variable, using the following code:
`JSON.parse('<?= json_encode($htmlString, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>')`

Unfortunaly, my javascript returns an error (`Unexpected token f`) because the double quote in the class declaration breaks the json string.

**Important:** This is a simplified version of the array I am actually encoding in JSON. The affected string is just a small part of a complex multilevel array.

Changing `$htmlString = '<div class="foo">bar</div>';` to `$htmlString = "<div class='foo'>bar</div>";` would be an option, but a bulky one (I would have to change about 500 views)

Does anyone have another solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to `JSON.parse`. You can do like this:

```
<script>
var html = <?= json_encode($htmlString) ?>;
</script>
```

The result of `json_encode` already contains valid javascript data.

Comment: Life is simple sometimes, I am worty of a wakeup slap to the forehead